# while ($t <= 1) not iterating for $t = 1

Tags: php, precision

I have a while loop which basically goes like that:

```
$t_step = <some value smaller than 1>;
$t = 0;

while ($t <= 1) {
  //do stuff
  $t += $t_step;
}
```

in some cases `$t` becomes `1`, but the loop does not iterate in that case.

if I am writing something like:

```
while($t <= 1.0001)
```

it goes on an produces the right result, but I don't think that this is ideal.

What can I do here?

BTW.:

I have already tried:

```
$t = 0.0;

while ($t <= 1.0) { … }
```

to indicate floating point values here…

**Update**

Due to the request in the comments:

```
 $t_step = 1 / $steps; //$step can be up one hundred right now
```

Comment: You need to give _<some value smaller than 1>_ that shows this.

Comment: I'd be using a `for` here, not a `while`. e.g. https://3v4l.org/5tMTn

Comment: How is $t_step generated? Could you be falling foul of floating point precision? See the warning here http://php.net/float

Comment: @chris85 is that just for performance, or does a for loop do a different kind of addition and comparison??

Comment: is `$steps` just the number of iterations? Why not just use a `for` loop? Are you using the `$steps` variable for some other calculation or something?  Maybe do that in the loop and use a `for`. It appears you're just wanting to iterate `$steps` times, right?

Comment: @philipp I don't think there is a performance difference, nor is the evaluation done differently. This should function the same. My example can be converted to a `while`, I just find the `for` syntax easier to read.

Comment: Welcome to floating-point arithmetic → https://3v4l.org/O1kif ... more info at  http://floating-point-gui.de/basic/

Comment: @chris85, if you replace your `$t_step = 1 / 100;` instead of `0.10` you'll still get the issue he's having.  What's wrong with doing this instead?  https://3v4l.org/drGkG

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comment of @chris85 the coin dropped and I could rewrite the whole thing like so:

```
 for ($i = 0; $i <= $steps; $i++) {
   $t = $i * $t_step;
   …
 }
```

That removes the numerical issues.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of iterating using a floating point value, just use your `$steps` to iterate, as I mentioned in the comments.

You can then use a for loop.

You can calculate your `$t_step` value within the loop and use it as you need.

```
$steps = 100; //or whatever value you're using

for ($i = 0; $i <= $steps; ++$i) {
  $t_step = $i / $steps;
}
```